# unable to locate package libprotobuf17

Tags: ubuntu

I tried to run `sudo apt-get install git cmake build-essential libboost-system-dev libprotobuf17 protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev openssl libssl-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev` in the ubuntu termianl to install MARIANNMT, but always got the error `unable to locate package libprotobuf17` I then tried `sudo apt install libprotobuf17` and `sudo apt-get install libprotobuf17` but the isntall failed given the error `unable to locate package libprotobuf17` Can anyone help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7ALw.png)

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu 22.04 repo has a later version of libprotobuf which is  libprotobuf23 so installing libprotobuf23 will do the job

```
sudo apt install libprotobuf23
```